# Find Original Install Date of Windows in Metro Application

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I want to get Original Install Date of Windows in my metro application. Can any expert give me the answer to this question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: First look how it it found in systems without Metro like XP/Vista/Win7. Then try to apply the same here in Metro.